# DNS IP как настроить домены правильно?

Tags: ip, dns, ispmanager

У меня 2 домена

xxxxx.zz

и

yyyyy.zz

Я их зарегистрировал на reg.ru. Хостинг у меня расположен в другом месте, на хостинге мне выдали 2 ip адреса (у меня арендован сервер).

123.123.123.11123.123.123.22

При регистрации доменов я для каждого указал следующие

ns1.xxxxx.zz 123.123.123.11ns2.xxxxx.zz 123.123.123.22

ns1.yyyyy.zz 123.123.123.11ns2.yyyyy.zz 123.123.123.22

Ок все работает. Но теперь при просмотре whois домен мне пишут, что на этом сервере находится 2 сайта

xxxxx.zzyyyyy.zz

Как мне прописать так, чтобы сайт xxxxx.zz находился на первом ip, а сайт yyyyy.zz находился на втором ip, чтобы гугл не мог определить, что они находятся на одном сервре?

На серевере у меня установлен ISPManadger, в нем я выставил для сайта yyyyy.zz второй ip, но при переходе на сайт yyyyy.zz меня перекидывает на xxxxx.zz.

Как быть? Кто в этом шарит?

Answer (score 2):

Нужно настроить виртуальные хосты apache. Попробуйте добавить в 1 хост <VirtualHost 123.123.123.11:80>, и соответственно во второй...[Apache IP-based Virtual Host Support](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ru/vhosts/ip-based.html).

Comment: Да в индейце хоть испишитесь, но если днс сервера не знают о привязке имен к ИП адресам, то все это работать не будет.

Answer (score 1):

> Как мне прописать так, чтобы сайт xxxxx.zz находился на первом ip, а сайт yyyyy.zz находился на втором ip

- xxxxx.zz 123.123.123.11
- yyyyy.zz 123.123.123.22